# How to read and display Xml in ListView and TextView

Tags: android, xml

This is XML Type

```
  <Category Name="Android">
    <Question><![CDATA[What is Android?]]></Question>
    <Answer><![CDATA[Android Is Programming Language.]]></Answer>
    <Question><![CDATA[What is Android?]]></Question>
    <Answer><![CDATA[Android Is Programming Language.]]></Answer>
    </Category>
    <Category Name="C#">

    </Category>
    <Category Name="SQL">

    </Category>
```

I want to show a Category of  ListItem , when click on item textview show question and in second textbox show that questions answer?, on button click show next question and answer, how i read this , i need hint..... Thanks

Comment: why you do't search for the answer?

Comment: How do you get xml data ? using SoapObject ?

Comment: no xml i have in res/xml forler